# How to use CoreData in Apportable?

Tags: android, core-data, apportable

I trying the full version of apportable and I have a problem with the CoreData:

I have the correct features at configuration.json:

```
"FEATURES": ["opengles2","landscape","prefer_external_storage","write_external_storage","write_settings"],
```

1. Setting the storageURL where I want to store the DB:

   ```
    #ifdef ANDROID
    //tried many different locations but not luck, I think there is the problem
    NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/data/data/com.bluepiggames.zombieSlice/files/Documents/ZS_SuperDatabase.db"];
    #else
    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"ZS_SuperDatabase"];
    #endif
   ```
2. Creating the persistenceCoordinatore:

   ```
   NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                                NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                                [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                                NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

   _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc]
                    initWithManagedObjectModel: [self managedObjectModel]];
   ```
3. Finally, these is the place where the app crash:

   ```
   if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error]) {
   NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
   //abort();
   ```

   And no error prompt in the debugger, only a crash like these.

   ```
   F/libc    (10177): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xe1a0d013 (code=1)
   D/dalvikvm( 7227): GC_CONCURRENT freed 387K, 12% free 6566K/7431K, paused 2ms+2ms
   D/IabHelper(10177): Querying SKU details.
   I/DEBUG   ( 8708): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
   I/DEBUG   ( 8708): Build fingerprint: 'SoftWinnner/crane_a1002jhenergy/crane-a1002jhenergy:4.0.4/IMM76D/20120822:eng/test-keys'
   I/DEBUG   ( 8708): pid: 10177, tid: 10218  >>> com.bluepiggames.zombieSlice <<<
   I/DEBUG   ( 8708): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr e1a0d013
   I/DEBUG   ( 8708):  r0 63c40b68  r1 6412b13c  r2 6412b13c  r3 00000000
   ```

(EDIT) To solve this crash we must set the before:

```
  NSError *error = nil. //!!!!!
  if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error])
```

Now the problem is in a different place:

```
// Returns the managed object model for the application.
// If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from the application's model.
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"ZSDataModel" withExtension:@"momd"];
    NSLog(@"Test managedModel found %@",modelURL);

    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}
```

And the error is because the DataModel compiled not found. Anybody knows how to put the compiled DataModel "DataModel.momod" inside a apportable project?

Thanks

Comment: Note that CoreData is not supported in the Starter SDK. If you have at least the Starter SDK, the best bet might be to send a full project demonstrating the issue to sdk@apportable.com. storeURL shouldn't need to be specified differently for Android than iOS.

Comment: Thanks Paul, but I'm testing the full version of Apportable. Maybe I try to send the project to sdk@apportable.com. Thank you.

Comment: I am having the same crash after addPersistentStoreWithType:. Also using the full version of Apportable.

Comment: I found one of the errors that caused the crash. I'm not initialazing the NSError *error = nil; (Edit to update the error)

Comment: Have you solved your problem. If so can you share the solution. I am having a similar issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry for such a late response, but i didn't want to let the question go unanswered. right now momd files aren't automatically added as assets. unfortunately, there's a manual step you'll need to do every time you update the xcdatamodeld.

1. navigate to your simulator's Applications directory (e.g. `~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/6.1/Applications/<randomString>/<YourApp>.app/`)
2. navigate into the momd directory
3. run the following in terminal: `plutil -convert xml1 <ModelName>.mom -o <pathNearYourApprojFolder>/<ModelName>.mom`
4. in your configuration.json in the `add_params` dictionary, then in the `assets` array, add the path `<pathRelativeToApprojFolder>/<ModelName>.mom` of the file you converted with plutil

Comment: what if i had different model versions of database?

Comment: Apportable now supports binary .mom files, so the conversion step to xml is no longer needed.

Comment: @Paul I'm having difficulty setting up the correct params when using CoreData. I already posted on the Apportable Forums and also here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23754932/what-is-the-correct-way-of-using-the-xcdatamodels-parameters-in-the-apportable-c I think this is the only issue I have now.