# Adding Persistent Store in Apportable

Tags: android, core-data, restkit, apportable

I am trialing the full version of Apportable, but cannot get it to successfully add a persistent store.
I am adding the persistent store via this code:

```
NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.pathToStoreFile];
NSError *error = nil;
_persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:_managedObjectModel];
// Allow inferred migration from the original version of the application.
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error]) {
    if (self.delegate != nil && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(managedObjectStore:didFailToCreatePersistentStoreCoordinatorWithError:)]) {
        [self.delegate managedObjectStore:self didFailToCreatePersistentStoreCoordinatorWithError:error];
    } else {
        NSAssert(NO, @"Managed object store failed to create persistent store coordinator: %@", error);
    }
}
```

This call returns false (failure).

```
[_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error]
```

Printing out the variables just before this call gives:

options:

```
{NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption = 1; NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption = 1; }
```

print-object storeURL

```
file://localhost/data/data/au.com.afgonline.flexcontacts/files/Documents/contacts.sqlite
```

I have added write_external_storage and write_settings to the features in configuration.json

Related to [How to use CoreData in Apportable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388775/how-to-use-coredata-in-apportable)

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: That call also takes an NSError parameter. If you look into that, it will probably contain a big clue to the source of the problem

Comment: Yes, NSError was the first think I looked at, but I forgot to mention in the question that the NSError is nil :(

Comment: unfortunately our current CoreData implementation is fairly minimal. in a soon-to-be-released version of our SDK, error will have more information more often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry it took me so long to see this question. the answer i gave in the related question ([How to use CoreData in Apportable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388775/how-to-use-coredata-in-apportable)) that you linked may be of interest to you. more importantly, we're soon going to be shipping a new version of our platform with a lot of important and useful changes. there will be a new version of coredata shipped with this as well. i hope to soon fix the manual copying step.