# Supporting coredata

Tags: core-data, apportable

I am using https://stackoverflow.com/a/20161667/644149 this link to support coredata in apportable.

**1-** i had number of model versions of my database so what name should i give in plutil command.

```
 plutil -convert xml1 <ModelName>.mom -o <pathNearYourApprojFolder>/<ModelName>.mom
```

**2-** when i put .mom file path in asset it gives given below error,
Thanks in advance

```
ROOTED=yes MTP=no apportable debug
Building with TARGET_ARCH_ABI:armeabi ARM_NEON:False
Building to /Users/username/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug
Loading configuration.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/.apportable/SDK/bin/apportable", line 820, in <module>
    run(env)
  File "/Users/username/.apportable/SDK/bin/apportable", line 756, in run
    results = actions[args.action](env)
  File "/Users/username/.apportable/SDK/bin/apportable", line 106, in DebugAction
    return env.DebugApp(site_init.BuildApplication(env, env['BUILD_TARGET']))
  File "/Users/username/.apportable/SDK/site_scons/site_init.py", line 401, in BuildApplication
    return build.App(env, app_sconscript)
  File "/Users/username/.apportable/SDK/site_scons/build/__init__.py", line 527, in App
    (sources, headers, defines, flags, configs, deps, libs, java_libs, assets, pchs, modules, java_sources, java_res_dirs, java_sourcepaths, link_flags) = Script(env, path, contents, use_absolute_paths=True, is_application=True)
  File "/Users/username/.apportable/SDK/site_scons/build/__init__.py", line 423, in Script
    if icon == asset['target']:
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 0):

Apportable now supports binary .mom files, so the conversion step to xml is no longer needed.

The format of the files added to the "assets" section in "add_params" of configuration.json should be wrapped in double quotes and comma separated.