# What is the correct way of using the xcdatamodels parameters in the apportable config file? I believe this is for using Core Data

Tags: apportable

Maybe I didn't set the correct APPORTABLE config parameters when using CoreData.  I can ADD,EDIT,DELETE and List down the current records when the app is running.  But when I remove it from the current running apps and tried to Open my app again all of the data are gone.  Maybe setting the correct parameter would eliminate this bug I am encountering right now?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to set the xcdatamodel list in the configuration.json unless you have a special apportable-specific xcdatamodel. the model *should* now automatically be compiled and put into the app bundle. in fact, if you were using our coredata before this change, i recommend undoing everything you have done in order to get it to work. it should just work.

as for your issue, would you mind creating a test case and then emailing it to sdk @ apportable.com? it's tough to debug without a reduced test case that demonstrates the bug.

**update**: we didn't have hasChanges properly implemented in NSManagedObjectContext. We've implemented it better, and now the test project works. Look for it the next version of the SDK (could be a few days to a week for that), and let me know if you still have trouble.

Comment: I just sent an email with the attached program I was using for test.

Comment: Almost forgot I stayed away from using magicalrecord because I can't compile them in Apportable there were a bunch of errors but that's ok.  Anyway I'm just saying.